# Prove that $\int_{-\pi}^\pi h_0(x) e^{i w x} d x=H_0(w)$ is an even function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $\{\lambda_n\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb R$ such that $\lambda_{-n}=-\lambda_n$. Suppose there exists a function $h_0(x)$ such that if
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi h_0(x) e^{i w x} d x=H_0(w)
$$
then
$$
H_0(0)=1, \quad H_0\left(\lambda_n\right)=0, \quad n \neq 0 .
$$
Prove that $H_0(w)$ is an even function.

**My attempt**

$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi h_0(x) e^{i \lambda_{-n} x} d x=H_0(\lambda_{-n})=H_0(-\lambda_{n})=\int_{-\pi}^\pi h_0(x) e^{-i \lambda_{n} x} d x=\int_{-\pi}^\pi h_0(-x) e^{i \lambda_{n} x} d x=0$$
because $H_0(\lambda_{-n})=H_0(-\lambda_{n})=0$ by assumption. Thus $H_0$ is even. Is it correct?

**Edit**

The problem has been taken from a part of the proof of a Theorem stated in the Levinson's Book "Gap and Density Theorems" (Proof of Theorem XIX). In this case the sequence was:
$$\begin{aligned}
\lambda_n & =n-\frac{p-1}{2 p}, \\
\lambda_0 & =0 \\
\lambda_{-n} & =-n+\frac{p-1}{2 p},
\end{aligned}$$
for $p=2$ and $n>0$. I thought that the consideration made by Levinson to prove his theorem were valid for all the sequences $\lambda_n$, I realized that I was wrong. Thank you all!

Comment: +1. You proved $H_0(x)$ is even on the sequence $\{\lambda_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$. Don't you need to show this is the case for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @gt6989b: in fact, but I don't know how to proceed...

Comment: Not sure myself. In what context did you received the problem? E.g., do you know about Laplace transforms?

Comment: Just to be sure, are there any regularity assumptions on $h_0$, or is it just any integrable function?

Comment: What has that Sequence got to do with that Integral ? Is Proof valid ONLY at Sequence values ? If YES , then what if the Integral is not 0 at other real values ? If NO , then why we require the Sequence ? What **Exactly** is $H_0(W)$ at all other values ?

Comment: More-over , what if the Sequence is $[\cdots,-1,-1,-1,0,+1,+1,+1,\cdots]$ ? Proof will only target $-1,0,+1$ , all other real values will be out of target. I am not sure : Something is off here.

Comment: @Prem For the sequence you chose, which is $\lambda_n = n$, $H_0(n)$ is the $-n$-th Fourier coefficient of $h_0$ ($-n$ because of the $e^{iwx}$ instead of $e^{-iwx}$) and you can show that $h_0$ is even iff its Fourier coefficients verify $c_{-n} = c_n$, which would be the case here, and thus $H_0$ will be even using the evenness of $h_0$ ($h_0$ is actually constant due to all but one coefficients being zero). The issue lies in extending this reasoning to other sequences $(\lambda_n)_n$ though.

Comment: I did not choose $\lambda_n=n$ , I chose $\lambda_n=sign(n)$ to get ONLY $-1,0,+1$ , @BrunoB , where no other real value is covered by the Sequence & the Integral. Except at these Points , the Integral & the function can have arbitrary values.

Comment: @Prem Right. I assume though that the $\lambda_n$s for nonnegative $n$ were supposed to be made distinct by whoever OP got the question from, but yes sequences with finitely many values won't work. Actually, this is making me think of a potential counterexample for infinitely many values too.

Comment: I too thought that this was wrong or OP was inaccurately reporting Original Question from Original Source , thus my Earlier Comment "Something is off here" : My Sequence is already the Counter-Example , @BrunoB , though my **DISTINCTNESS** Counter-Example Sequence is $\lambda_0=0,\lambda_n=1/n$ where Integral & function outside $[-1,+1]$ will be arbitrary. The Question in Current form is invalid. More-over , OP Attempt is nothing more than a restatement of given Criteria !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample to your claim: consider the function $h_0 : x \mapsto \sin x + \displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi}$ and the sequence $(\lambda_n)_n$ defined by $\lambda_0 := 0$, $\lambda_n := n+1$ for $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$ and $\lambda_{-n} := -\lambda_n$.
Then, we have that $H_0(0) = 1$, $H_0(\lambda_n) = 0$ (as stated in one of my comments above, $H(-m)$ for an integer $m$ is the $m$-th Fourier coefficient of $h_0$, thus these first equalities are easy to see if you know a bit about Fourier series), yet, for $w \neq 0$ :
$$\begin{split}
H_0(-w) &= \int_{-\pi}^\pi \left(\sin x + \frac{1}{2\pi}\right)\,e^{-iwx} \mathrm{d}x\\
&= \int_{-\pi}^\pi \left(\sin (-x) + \frac{1}{2\pi}\right) \,e^{iwx} \mathrm{d}x\\
&= - \int_{-\pi}^\pi \left(\sin x + \frac{1}{2\pi}\right)\,e^{iwx} \mathrm{d}x + 2\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{1}{2\pi}\,e^{iwx} \mathrm{d}x\\
&= -H_0(w) + \frac{1}{\pi iw}\left(e^{iw\pi} - e^{-iw\pi}\right)\\
&= -H_0(w) + \frac{2}{w\pi}\sin(w\pi)
\end{split}$$
Thus, if $H_0$ was even, we would have $H_0(w) = \displaystyle\frac{\sin(w\pi)}{w\pi}$.

However, for $|w| \neq 1$ (the first equality is left as a quick calculation):
$$\begin{split}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin x \,e^{iwx} \mathrm{d}x &= \frac{\sin((w+1)\pi)}{i(w+1)} - \frac{\sin((w-1)\pi)}{i(w-1)}\\
&= i\sin((w+1)\pi)\left(\frac{1}{w-1} - \frac{1}{w+1}\right)\\
&= 2i\frac{\sin((w+1)\pi)}{w^2 - 1}
\end{split}$$
Hence, for $w \notin \{-1, 0, 1\}$ :
$$H_0(w) = 2i\frac{\sin((w+1)\pi)}{w^2 - 1} + \frac{\sin(w\pi)}{w\pi}$$
Taking any $w$ such that the imaginary part isn't zero, $w = \frac{1}{2}$ for example, shows that $H_0(w) \neq \frac{\sin(w\pi)}{w\pi}$, and as such that $H_0$ is not even due to what was observed previously.